# Why am I getting an inferring latch error?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, vivado

I'm trying to create a vending machine in System Verilog using an FSM, and during synthesis, the software warned me with this error:

> [Synth 8-327] inferring latch for variable
> 'FSM_sequential_statoProssimo_reg' ["MacchinettaMerendine.sv":87]

The code is:

```
...
module FSM_50_Cent (
    input logic Clk100_MHz, Reset,
    input logic Cent20, Cent50, Euro1, Confirm,
    input logic [7:0] Switch50,
    output logic Er, r10, r20, r40, r50
    );

    enum logic [4:0] {S0, S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9,
                      S10, S11, S12, S13, S14, S15, S16, S17} Stati;  //STATES

    logic [4:0] Stato, statoProssimo;                                 //STATE AND NEXTSTATE

    always_ff @(posedge Clk100_MHz, posedge Reset)                    //FLIP FLOP
        begin 
            if(Reset)   Stato <= S0;

            else        Stato <= statoProssimo;

        end

    always_comb                                                       //NEXT STATE LOGIC
        begin
            if((|Switch50) == 1)
                begin
                    case(Stato) 

                        S0:     if (Cent20)          statoProssimo = S1;
                                else if (Cent50)     statoProssimo = S3;
                                else if (Euro1)      statoProssimo = S8;
                                else if (Confirm)    statoProssimo = S0;

                        S1:     if (Cent20)          statoProssimo = S2;
                                else if (Cent50)     statoProssimo = S5;
                                else if (Euro1)      statoProssimo = S9;
                                else if (Confirm)    statoProssimo = S1;

                        S2:     if (Cent20)          statoProssimo = S4;
                                else if (Cent50)     statoProssimo = S7;
                                else if (Euro1)      statoProssimo = S10;
                                else if (Confirm)    statoProssimo = S2;

                        S3:     if (Confirm)         statoProssimo = S0;

                        S4:     if (Confirm)         statoProssimo = S0;

                        S5:     if (Confirm)         statoProssimo = S0;

                        S6:     if (Confirm)         statoProssimo = S0;

                        S7:     if (Confirm)         statoProssimo = S0;
                                
                        S8:     if (Confirm)         statoProssimo = S0;

                        S9:     if (Confirm)         statoProssimo = S0;

                        S10:    if (Confirm)         statoProssimo = S0;
                        
                        default                      statoProssimo = S0;

                    endcase
                end
        end
...

endmodule
...
```

And the error is on this line: `S0:     if (Cent20)          statoProssimo = S1;`

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid a latch, the `always_comb` block must assign a value to `statoProssimo` under all conditions.

However, the block does not assign a value to `statoProssimo` when `Switch50` is 0, for example.  Therefore, the Verilog simulation will retain the value of `statoProssimo`.  This infers a memory element (a latch).

You could add an `else` clause and assign a value.  For example:

```
always_comb                    //NEXT STATE LOGIC
    begin
        if((|Switch50) == 1)
            begin
                case(Stato) 
                 ...
                endcase
            end
        else statoProssimo = S0;
    end
```

The same applies for each of the `case` items.  You should use an `else` clause to assign a value.

```
                S0:     if (Cent20)          statoProssimo = S1;
                        else if (Cent50)     statoProssimo = S3;
                        else if (Euro1)      statoProssimo = S8;
                        else                 statoProssimo = S0;
```

You need to decide what value to assign in each case.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the toolic explanation of answer and see the `always_comb` section of this code.

```
module FSM_50_Cent (
  input  logic       Clk100_MHz, Reset,
  input  logic       Cent20, Cent50, Euro1, Confirm,
  input  logic [7:0] Switch50,
  output logic       Er, r10, r20, r40, r50
);

  typedef enum logic [4:0] {S0, S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9,
                    S10, S11, S12, S13, S14, S15, S16, S17} Stati;  //STATES

  Stati Stato, statoProssimo; //STATE AND NEXTSTATE

  //STATE FLIP FLOPS
  always_ff @(posedge Clk100_MHz, posedge Reset)                    
    if(Reset)   Stato <= S0;
    else        Stato <= statoProssimo;

  //NEXT STATE LOGIC
  always_comb  begin
    statoProssimo = Stato;
      if((|Switch50) == 1)
        case(Stato)
          S0:     if      (Cent20)     statoProssimo = S1;
                  else if (Cent50)     statoProssimo = S3;
                  else if (Euro1)      statoProssimo = S8;
                  else if (Confirm)    statoProssimo = S0;
          S1:     if      (Cent20)     statoProssimo = S2;
                  else if (Cent50)     statoProssimo = S5;
                  else if (Euro1)      statoProssimo = S9;
                  else if (Confirm)    statoProssimo = S1;
          S2:     if      (Cent20)     statoProssimo = S4;
                  else if (Cent50)     statoProssimo = S7;
                  else if (Euro1)      statoProssimo = S10;
                  else if (Confirm)    statoProssimo = S2;
          S3,S4,
          S5,S6,
          S7,S8,
          S9,S10: if (Confirm)         statoProssimo = S0;
          default                      statoProssimo = S0;
        endcase
  end
```